# Drawing a textured quad pixel-exact in 2D with OpenGL 3.3?

Tags: c++, opengl, smooth-scrolling, texturing, pixel-perfect

How to scroll a textured quad "pixel-exact" over the screen
using float-positions with GL_LINEAR-filtering?
If I try this task, I could always see a hard pixel-change
during the very smooth movement if a subpixels-coordinate is
greater or equal than 0.5.This looks like a really ugly stuttering.

I think the problem is here, that after scrolling 0.5 subpixels
the quad is so misaligned to the texture-coordinates, that OpenGL
takes now another neighbour pixel for texturing which is newly
interpolated and so the new drawn subpixel is not aligned to
the rendered subpixel before?!

Could be the solution here, to realign the texture-coordinates
on positions > 0.5f? Can somebody help me out with a function,
that deals with this problem and calculates the right uv-coordinates?
I think the uv-coordinates should moved to a new position
if the quads subpixel-position is >= 0.5f.

Here is a link to screenshot, that shows exact the hard pixel-jump
in x-direction (left) on x=0.5f in the last frame. 
(zoom the screenshot with strg+mousewheel)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0GVA.png

Here are the relevant code-fragments:

```
float calcTexPos(float fTexPos,float spriteX, float spriteY){return (fTexPos)/(64.0f);}

void addSpriteToLocalVerticeArray(Vertex * ptrVertexArrayLocal, Sprite *sprite, int *ptrSpriteVerticeCounter, float fCamX, float fCamY)
{
    Sprite oSpriteTranslated = *sprite;
    oSpriteTranslated.x = (sprite->x) - (fCamX);
    oSpriteTranslated.y = (sprite->y) - (fCamY);

ptrVertexArrayLocal[(*ptrSpriteVerticeCounter)++] = Vertex(oSpriteTranslated.x,oSpriteTranslated.y,0.0f,calcTexPos(1,oSpriteTranslated.x,oSpriteTranslated.y),calcTexPos(62,oSpriteTranslated.x,oSpriteTranslated.y));                                                     //Left Top
ptrVertexArrayLocal[(*ptrSpriteVerticeCounter)++] = Vertex(oSpriteTranslated.x,oSpriteTranslated.y-oSpriteTranslated.height,0.0f,calcTexPos(1,oSpriteTranslated.x,oSpriteTranslated.y),calcTexPos(31,oSpriteTranslated.x,oSpriteTranslated.y));                            //Left Bottom
ptrVertexArrayLocal[(*ptrSpriteVerticeCounter)++] = Vertex(oSpriteTranslated.x+oSpriteTranslated.width,oSpriteTranslated.y-oSpriteTranslated.height,0.0f,calcTexPos(33,oSpriteTranslated.x,oSpriteTranslated.y),calcTexPos(31,oSpriteTranslated.x,oSpriteTranslated.y));   //Right Bottom
ptrVertexArrayLocal[(*ptrSpriteVerticeCounter)++] = Vertex(oSpriteTranslated.x+oSpriteTranslated.width,oSpriteTranslated.y-oSpriteTranslated.height,0.0f,calcTexPos(33,oSpriteTranslated.x,oSpriteTranslated.y),calcTexPos(31,oSpriteTranslated.x,oSpriteTranslated.y));   //Right Bottom   
ptrVertexArrayLocal[(*ptrSpriteVerticeCounter)++] = Vertex(oSpriteTranslated.x+oSpriteTranslated.width,oSpriteTranslated.y,0.0f,calcTexPos(33,oSpriteTranslated.x,oSpriteTranslated.y),calcTexPos(62,oSpriteTranslated.x,oSpriteTranslated.y));                            //Right Top
ptrVertexArrayLocal[(*ptrSpriteVerticeCounter)++] = Vertex(oSpriteTranslated.x,oSpriteTranslated.y,0.0f,calcTexPos(1,oSpriteTranslated.x,oSpriteTranslated.y),calcTexPos(62,oSpriteTranslated.x,oSpriteTranslated.y));                                                     //Left Top
}
```

What I have tried that didn't work:

- Adding an offset of 0.5f to my quad-coords. That moves the problem to the stage, that
  now each full 1.0f subpixel-position a hard subpixel-change appears.
- Changing the calcTexPos-Function: -> (2.0f*fTexPos+1.0f)/(2.0f*64.0f)
- Checking, If MSAA is activated on the driver-panel
- Added transparent borders to the texture instead of copied borders

Comment: That's a lot of text, and a lot of code. I had to read it twice to find the question. Can you explain it in a shorter way? can you define "color-irritations", or even better, include a screenshot

Comment: One option is to add a 'buffer' of pixels around each tile texture (where you have red, yellow etc.) so that any sampling outside that texture still picks up the right colour. There is probably a better way if you keep searching

Comment: Reworked the whole question now. I already added a buffer around my tile, but this solved not the problem :(

Comment: Your texture doesn't tile. Copy and paste the image beside itself

Comment: Verified this. If I am padding now 1 pixel with the opposite border-pixels,
then all is perfect and ultrasmooth also on subpixel-positions! Perfect!
But the problem is only partial solved. If I want to use more than 1 tile-graphic
for scrolling, than there is again the pixel-jump now on the edges beetween
aligned DIFFERENT tiles. Aligned equal Tiles look smooth. Is the problem
solvable, or what are my options now? I could render all tiles for a frame
to an offset-texture and then the whole-tile-context will be interpolated?

Comment: Take a look at this question on the gamedev page http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/46963/how-to-avoid-texture-bleeding-in-a-texture-atlas you're basically making a "texture atlas"

Comment: Hi Tom, first great thnx for u engagement. Of course I am using a Texture-Atlas. I have a whole engine finished with physics, texture-manager, shadows and so on. I am working on a turrican-like clone. The ONLY thing is the damn stuttering, when moving on subpixels. I will do now scroll only on full integers...its a little bit stuttering, but the textureing is exact. Maybe the task is not solvable on subpixels...for example I analyzed the scrolling on the game "hurrican", they use full integers too (I could not see any subpixel-movements!)...with some reason I think.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help you further, I would have expected someone with more experience to come along by now. If you do end up solving your issue, then you should answer your own question here so that others with the same problem know what to do.